# Switch between making API call, and setting mocked data without an API call in SWIFT

Tags: swift, swiftui

During the development of a swiftUI project, I wish to have option to switch the way data is set, either

1. Allowing API calls to be made as normal which sets an @Published variable, or
2. Set the @published variable from mocked file and NOT make the api call.

The reason is that I am limited to the number of api calls per minute.

In my example below I load the mocked data in a model called "Person".

**Current solution**

- Set a global variable to distinguish between the two above mentioned states.
- In **all** places where api calls were be made, I introduce a condition to optionally use mocked data and not make the api call. See `.task`  in MyView

```swift
struct GlobalConstants {
    static let use_mock_data = true
}
```

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Person] = []
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchData() async {
        // ... data is set in this code
    }
    
}
```

Within Person model, I set a static variable that returns the decoded mock data from a json file. The `decode` method below is an extension to Bundle (Thanks Paul Hudsen).

```swift
extension Person {
    static var mockPersons: [Person] {
        Bundle.main.decode([Person].self, from: "persons.json")
    }
    
}
```

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    @StateObject var vm = PersonViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(vm.data) { d in
                    NavigationLink {
                        OtherView(prop: d.detail)
                    } label: {
                     Text(d.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {   // -----condition--------------------- //
                if GlobalConstants.use_mock_data {
                    vm.data = Person.mockPersons
                } else {
                    await vm.fetchData()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Question**

What other approaches can I consider for enabling the two states? Overriding the methods in some way?

I am still on the learning curve to swift and wondering if theres a better way to enable long term maintenance in a clean and predictable way.

Answer (score 0):

As fetching the data belongs to the view model my suggestion is to put the condition into `fetchData`.

Marking a method as `async` doesn't require necessarily that the executed code is asynchronous

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people: [Person] = []
           
    func fetchData() async {
        if GlobalConstants.use_mock_data {
            people = Person.mockPersons
        } else {
            // people = await callTheAPI()
        }
    }   
}
```

and replace the task in the view with

```
.task {  
     await vm.fetchData()
}
```

Note: `people` is a more meaningful name than `data`

Comment: Thats a great tip about moving the logic.

Comment: Is there a way to initialise the view model with the mocked data?  Determined by a parameter passed in to the viewmodel? Currently reading up on convenience  initialiser, seems like something could be done

Comment: Yes, just implement `init()` or even with a parameter and a default value `init(mocked: Bool = true)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Service with a protocol, and then create 2 services extending the protocol, one for mock and one for data, here are some examples from one of my apps (using alamofire, but you can modify it to use it with URLSession or anything else) :

```swift
import Alamofire


class NetworkManager {
    func get<T: Decodable>(url: URLConvertible, parameters: Parameters?,_ completion: @escaping (DataResponse<T, AFError>) -> Void) {
        AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
        .responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
            completion(response)
        }
    }
}

protocol SearchServicing {
    var parameters: Parameters? { get set }
    func get(_ completion: @escaping (Result<SearchResponse, AFError>) -> Void)
}

class SearchService: NetworkManager, SearchServicing {
    var parameters: Parameters?
    
    func get(_ completion: @escaping (Result<SearchResponse, AFError>) -> Void) {
        let url = "YOUR_URL"
        
        get(url: url, parameters: parameters) { response in
            completion(response.result)
        }
    }
}

class SearchMockService: SearchServicing {
    var parameters: Parameters?
    var getCallCounter = 0
    
    func get(_ completion: @escaping (Result<SearchResponse, AFError>) -> Void) {
        getCallCounter += 1
        
        let response = SearchResponse(recipes: [
            Recipe.mock,
            Recipe.mock,
            Recipe.mock,
        ])
        
        completion(.success(response))
    }
}
```

Then add it in the ViewModel :

```swift
@MainActor
class RecipeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
    
    private var service: SearchServicing
    
    init(service: SearchServicing) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    public func fetchData() {
        [...]

        service.parameters = ["q": ingredients.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: " ")]
        
        service.get { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let searchResponse):
                self?.totalResults = searchResponse.count
                self?.results = searchResponse.recipes
            case .failure(let error):
                dump(error)
                self?.error = AppError(error: error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And so it allows me to do :

```swift
struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView(recipeViewModel: RecipeViewModel(service: SearchMockService()))
    }
}
```

whenever I need to test my view model and

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedResults(RecipeEntity.self) var favorites
    @StateObject var recipeViewModel = RecipeViewModel(service: SearchService())
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

for non mock datas service

For more informations checkout this video, it helped me to use this structure : [How to implement a Mock in Swift!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx-kTkhzthk)